# The fixing is complete

Tags: grammar

1. The fixing is complete.
2. The fix is complete.
3. The repair is complete.

Are these forms all ok? What does the first mean compaired to the second?

Comment: It would help if you provided more context. What is being fixed? A sentence? An engine? A tear in a pair of pants? A leaky faucet? We don't necessarily use the same words for all of these.

Comment: Be careful with 'fix' - depending on context it can have negative meanings (relating to bribery or drug use).  Your third option is grammatically correct and avoids any possible ambiguity.

Comment: @PerryW - That's a good point; however, more often than not, context will prevent that ambiguity. If I overhear someone in a restaurant saying, "Everything's fixed," I might wonder if something crooked is going on. But if my plumber reappears from under my kitchen cabinet, and announces, "Everything's fixed!" there's no ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 1 makes sense, but it isn't really the best option. Sentences 2 and 3 are fine.

However, the best way to say it would probably be:

> It has been fixed.

or

> It has been repaired.

You will likely find that you hear either of these two options more frequently than the last two examples you provided.

Comment: Thank you. Then when you say fixing as in the first, what does it exactly mean?

Comment: @JoeKim You're welcome. I think with the first one it is just a matter of there being a better alternative - it's not incorrect per se; there's just a better/more common way of saying it.

Comment: I think _"The repair is done"_ might be okay, when talking about, say, car repair.

Comment: The first one seems odd because emphasizes the end of the fixing process, whereas what most people want to know is just the end result -- the thing is not broken now. You might say other things in that structure, though, like for example "The fighting is over" would be common because in that case it is important is that the process has stopped, not the end result.

Comment: @joseph_morris Thank you for helping me out there. That was pretty much my thought process; I just couldn't describe it adequately.

Comment: I imagine a mechanic jumping up from under the car and saying "The fixing is complete!" It sounds like something Gandalf would say (if he were a mechanic). I'm not sure why that's the case -- I guess wizards have the appearance of being inherently interested in processes :^)

Comment: Complete, the fixing is. - Yoda